# Polite and informal word contractions

Tags: politeness, informal, contractions

In formal English, the general rule is to avoid word contractions, for example, "I am visiting on Thursday" is formal, whereas in informal English, one could say "I'm visiting on Thursday".

My question is: Is there any equivalent to this in German?  In a formal letter would I write "ich bin in dem Büro", but in an informal email I would write "ich bin im Büro".  Or "in dem Herbst"?

Below is a table of German contractions, and I have marked the ones that I suspect are only to be used in informal German:

an + dem = am

an + das = ans

auf + das = aufs

**außer + dem = außerm <- Not in dict.cc or Langenscheidt or DWDS**

bei + dem = beim

durch + das = durchs

für + das = fürs

**hinter + das = hinters <- INFORMAL**

**hinter + den = hintern <- INFORMAL + Not in dict.cc or Langenscheidt**

**hinter + dem = hinterm <- INFORMAL + Not in Langenscheidt**

in + das = ins

in + dem = im

**neben + das = nebens <- INFORMAL + Not in dict.cc or Langenscheidt or DWDS**

**über + das = übers <- INFORMAL + Not in Langenscheidt**

**über + den = übern <- INFORMAL + Not in Langenscheidt**

**über + dem = überm <- INFORMAL + Not in Langenscheidt**

um + das = ums

**unter + das = unters <- INFORMAL + Not in Langenscheidt**

**unter + den = untern <- INFORMAL + Not in Langenscheidt + Low usage**

**unter + dem = unterm <- INFORMAL + Not in Langenscheidt**

**vor + das = vors <- INFORMAL + Not in Langenscheidt**

**vor + dem = vorm <- INFORMAL**

**vor + den = vorn <- INFORMAL + Not in DWDS**

von + dem = vom

zu + dem = zum

zu + der = zur

**Unofficial contractions**

**geht + es = geht's <- INFORMAL**

**sie + es = sie's <- INFORMAL**

Comment: The ones that use an apostrophe aren't really official contractions, just a way of spelling what people actually say instead of the correct spelling, a bit like "yer" and "wanna" in English. So no, don't use them in a formal letter.

Comment: There is a difference between **polite** and **formal** -- maybe change that wording. _Aufm Berg_ is not impolite, but informal.

Comment: @phipsgabler: Yes, the issue is more complex than a binary polite vs. informal. I'm getting the impression that some of these words are dated or restricted to poetry. There are inappropriate levels of politeness too, for example I don't think you'd use *Ihr* instead of *Sie* in a business letter.

Comment: Is "I am visiting on Thursday" really just formal in english? I don't think so. It is more explicit than "I'm visiting", because it emphasizes that I _am_ (really) going to visit.

Comment: Nobody would write "Ich bin in dem Büro" say in a business e-mail, unless they wanted to specify *that* office. "Ich bin noch bis Freitag _im_ Büro und danach _im_ Urlaub." is a totally fine way to write a formal letter (although you would probably rather phrase it "Ich befinde mich...")

Answer (score 1):

Yes, avoid contractions in formal letters also in German. Except "am", "im", "vom", "ins" which are OK here (because that's neutral), and splitting them into "*n + dem" is just an additional level of formality.

Comment: Or even a level of anachronism. Might even be perceived as snobby.